# Loki in the Avengers

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-avengers-2012, loki

Why is Loki always looking so annoyed when someone mentions he is Thor´s brother?

Or am I mistaken?

Comment: -1 I think this is fairly obvious from their past events

Comment: @Pureferret - I give things a slide when they aren't in the immediate film, though I definitely wouldn't vote this up.

Comment: Yeah! I know it´s an unspectacular question, but you helped me a lot though! :) @wraith808

Answer (score 10):

[Little Brother Syndrome](http://www.dictionarydb.com/little%20brother%20syndrome).  He has grown up in the shadow of his older, more accomplished brother.  Add to that the fact that he is obviously weaker, though arguably more intelligent [in a culture that prizes strength over intellect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loki_%28comics%29#Fictional_character_biography), and the fact that he is adopted, and yes, he gets quite annoyed when reminded of that, though he is not above using it to his advantage.

Comment: Little Brother Syndrome! ;) haha THANK YOU!! A very good and interesting explanation, you answered my question perfectly well.. Exactly what I´ve been looking for.. :)

Comment: Cool, so I wasn´t mistaken.. :) But you´re right! He could use it easily!

Comment: Funny how the comics portray Asgardian culture as one that "Prizes strength over Intellect" when Odin is the Norse god of Wisdom and Intelligence.... The only Pantheonic Leader-God to be so.

Comment: Yeah, you´re right, good point!:D That´s really funny, I haven´t known that Odin is the Norse god of Wisdom and Intelligence.. Odin is wise AND a good and strong warrior (years ago), but Thor is only strong without being intelligent! :D

Comment: Ashley, in the Avengers Loki talks about "I've seen the true power of the Tesseract and when I wield it.." and Thor interrupts him immediately with "Who has shown you this true power? Who controls the would-be king?" That's a pretty good show of intelligence, so I don't think you can write Thor off like that.

Comment: @silvith - that's why I say in the answer 'arguably' more intelligent.  Thor had (has?) a problem with control, especially when his blood gets up.  He's also easily able to be manipulated in that state.  But he is capable of critical thinking.